# How to use "if clause" in xhtml?

Tags: xhtml, internet-explorer-6, if-statement

i am a newbie C# Programmer. I have a problem in xhtml. I want to check that if browser is IE6 or not. For example if ie6 then div id="div1" style="display:block;" else div id="div1" style="display:none;">
How can i control my browser and use if clause in xhtml?

Comment: Do you mean conditional comments (which is specific to IE, and not an XHTML feature)?

Comment: @Kenny: The nice thing about those is that they aren't invalid markup either. As far as non-specified features go, this was one I'd loved to have had in other browsers too. Contrary to popular opinion all non-IE browsers do also have implementation bugs :)

Comment: i found something like that and this is what i want:
<%   int BrowserStatus;
                 BrowserStatus = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].ToString().IndexOf("MSIE 6.0");
                 if (BrowserStatus > -1)

                {

                    Response.Write("1");

                }

                else 

                {

                    Response.Write("2");

                }
         %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

conditional comments are easiest, you can also do it server side...

```
<% if (HttpContext.Request.UserAgent.Contains("internet explorer 6")) //Not sure what the exact name is, need to look it up.
{%>
   //HTML
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign to your div one permanent style:

```
<div id="div1" class="jumping-div"></div>
```

Define the default style:

style1.css:

```
div.jumping-div
{
    display:none;
}
```

Then create another stylesheet which will redefine the class:

style2.css:

```
div.jumping-div
{
    display:block;
}
```

Then using conditional checks you can include another stylesheet:

```
<link href="style1.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link href="style1.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: i know this but this is not what i am looking for, i have to use "else" statement too?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no "else" part. Check the specs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx